# Using MKNetworkKit to parse JSON Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, mknetworkkit

Can anyone give an example using MKNetworkKit to parse JSON Data from the server using POST method using and ASynchronous request in objective c?

I have done it by using the *NSMutableRequest* and using the parameters as username and password, I wanted to explore the options of using the third party tools for it.

```
NSDictionary jsonDict = @{@"user":@{
                        @"password":txtPassword.text,
                        @"email":txtUsername.text}};
NSData jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict
                                                  options:0 error:0];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable err)
{
    NSString *dtaa = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"got response==%@", dtaa);
}];
```

Comment: what kind of problem you have met?

Comment: I'm trying to parse JSON data into a string, I used two parameters username and password, the console returns the result and i want that result to store in a string.

Comment: you are describing problem without code, super general, it is impossible to be helpful in such case. It is like: "my car has broken down, it is a red car. Engine is not starting. Help me!"

Comment: `code`   NSDictionary *jsonDict = @{@"user":@{@"password":txtPassword.text, @"email":txtUsername.text}};
    NSData* jsonData =  [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:0];
  [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable err)
     {
         NSString *dtaa = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
         NSLog(@"got response==%@", dtaa);

     }];